# Matrix of linear transformation is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum

Let $V$ and $W$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $P_V$ be orthogonal projection on $V$. The linear operator $T:V \to V$ is the restriction of $P_V\circ P_W$ to $V$. Prove that matrix associated with $T$ is symmetric in every orthonormal basis of $V$.

**My try:** The matrix of orthogonal projection is symmetric but product of symmetric matrices isn't necessarily symmetric and so this not works. I think we should use direct sum here but don't know how it can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the symmetric matrix $S = P_VP_WP_V$. Then $V$ is an invariant subspace of $S$ and $T = S|_V$. So, $T$ is symmetric in $V$.

Or directly: If $u,v\in V$, then
$$
\langle P_VP_Wu,v\rangle = \langle P_Wu,P_Vv\rangle = \langle P_Wu,v\rangle = \langle u,P_Wv\rangle = \langle P_Vu,P_Wv\rangle = \langle u,P_VP_Wv\rangle.
$$
Hence, $\langle Tu,v\rangle = \langle u,Tv\rangle$.

Now, if $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$, then the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to this basis is $(\langle Te_j,e_i\rangle)_{i,j=1}^r$, which is clearly symmetric.

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: I edited again. Now, it should be clear.

Comment: What do you mean by $T = S|_V$ and why $S = P_VP_WP_V$ is symmetric?

Comment: $S|_V$ is the restriction of $S$ to $V$. And $P_VP_WP_V$ is symmetric because $(P_VP_WP_V)^T = P_V^TP_W^TP_V^T = P_VP_WP_V$.

Comment: If you are content with my answer, please check it. Thanks.

Comment: So the matrix of $T$ is symmetric with respect to basis of $V$ not $\mathbb{R}^n$, right?

Comment: And can you say why $(\langle Te_j,e_i\rangle)_{i,j=1}^r$ is the matrix representation of $T$? How did you get that? If you explicitly write that in the matrix notation, it would be helpful for me.

Comment: This IS matrix notation. Do you know how you get the matrix representation with respect to a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$? You compute $Te_k$ in terms of the basis vectors and put the coefficients into to $k$-th column. Here, because we have an orthonormal basis, for any vector $v\in V$ we have $v=\sum_{j=1}^n\langle x,e_j\rangle e_j$. Hence $Te_k = \sum_{j=1}^n\langle Te_k,e_j\rangle e_j$. Thus, your matrix entries are the $\langle Te_k,e_j\rangle$'s.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so the matrix of $T$ is symmetric with respect to basis of $V$ not $\mathbb{R}^n$, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. With respect to *any* orthonormal basis. As claimed in the exercise.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words, S.H.W.